# Smarty. how to concat variable inside of replace sector

Tags: smarty

I tried following code for Smarty template, and bumped in an error.

```
{$phrases.build_rep_count_attend|replace:'{count}':'<font class="current-count"></font><font class="total-count">'.{$row.i_count}.'</font>'}
```

I also tried

```
{$phrases.build_rep_count_attend|replace:'{count}':'<font class="current-count"></font><font class="total-count">'|concat:{$row.i_count}|concat:'</font>'}
```

But no lucky.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. 
I have solved the issue by using concat 2 times continuously like following:

```
{$phrases.build_rep_count_attend|replace:'{count}':'<font class="current-count"></font><font class="total-count">{count}</font>'|replace:'{count}':{$row.i_count}}
```